# How to clear website cache from windows 10 or from all browsers

Tags: windows, windows-10, cache, browser-cache

i having problem with one of my websites its reload cache version when i am using VPN it working fine with current version but without VPN it reloads cache. **i a m using windows 10 and same problem in all browsers.**

Answer (score 0):

From HowToGeek's article [47 Keyboard Shortcuts That Work in All Web Browsers](https://www.howtogeek.com/114518/47-keyboard-shortcuts-that-work-in-all-web-browsers/)

> Ctrl+F5 – Reload and skip the cache, re-downloading the entire website.

Comment: i tried all methods from browser like empty cache and hard reload but no one works website works perfectly in mobile or vpn

Comment: "`

i having problem with one of my websites i`" - a website which you visit, or a website which you own? If the latter, you can add a "clear cache" button & some JS to do it.

Comment: a website that i own

Comment: Then I suggest adding a button to clear the cache from JS ...

Comment: website is on Laravel framework and i did this from artisan command but it didn't help me and website is fine problem is windows cache

Comment: There are plenty of browser plug-ins to clear cache, so it should be possible - somehow